# How to parse shell style config in python

Tags: python

all,

I'm working on some scripts, I have a shell style config file like this:

```
A=1
B=2
```

Now I have to write a python script, and use this config file for some value. Someone said to use ConfigureParser module of python(codes like this), but I got error.

```
>>> import ConfigParser
>>> cf = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
>>> cf.read("config")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 305, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 512, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: config, line: 1
'A=1\n'
```

I can't use python ConfigParser style config file, which means the config file is just like above, could not change it. So how to parse shell style config in python? Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import configparser
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()

try:
    with open(YourConfigFilePath) as f:
        config.readfp(f)
except:
    print("Config file Don't exist.")

# Check the config variable
print(config)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config')

print('IP' in config)
print(config.sections())
print((config['IP']['A']))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
True
['IP']
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`config.read_string()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_string) method to parse a config string instead of a filename. You can then use a string header to change the format of the config file in-memory:

```
import configparser

# Slurp in file contents
with open('example.cfg') as ec:
    cfg_data = ec.read()

# Insert a section header
cfg_data = "[default]\n\n" + cfg_data


# Now read the configuration:
cfgparser = configparser.ConfigParser()
cfgparser.read_string(cfg_data, source='example.cfg')
```